# Changing the layout of startActivityForResult in FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have just implemented FirebaseUI from [Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md) and it works fine. The problem i am having is that i want to change the layout when the new Activity is called as it doesn't look very good. Below is the

[image: Screenshot]

I am aware that we can change the theme of the Activity as :

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance(this).createSignInIntentBuilder()
        // ...
        .setTheme(R.style.AppThemeWithActionBar)
        .build());
```

But is there anyway that we can change the layout of the called activity ?

Comment: Can't you change the style?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AuthMethodPickerLayout and provide a Layout as below

```
   val authUILayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout.Builder(R.layout.auth_ui)
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.btn_gmail)
            .setEmailButtonId(R.id.btn_email)
            .setFacebookButtonId(R.id.btn_facebook)
            .build()
```

And than pass it in your intent as below

```
   val intent = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(
                listOf(
                    AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().setScopes(googleScopes).build(),
                    AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
                )
            )
            .enableAnonymousUsersAutoUpgrade()
            .setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authUILayout)
            .build()
```

Answer (score -1):

there is lots of ways to change the layout, they provided overrides to there styles. so add a style like this for example:

```
 <style name="AppThemeWithActionBar" parent="FirebaseUI">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/firebaseui_bg_image</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FirebaseUI.Text">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FirebaseUI.CountrySpinner">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText.EmailField">
        <item name="android:inputType">textEmailAddress</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>

    </style>

    <style name="FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText.PhoneField">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

run the program and see the layout has changed. Also in android studio click on FirebaseUI while holding command key or alt key maybe in windows (not sure) and you can see all the overrides.